# How do I merge an array with PHP Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have cloned HTML prepared with input group. Some checkbox and radio are not selected. I want to push into the selected email.

I've tried many methods.

`array_merge()`

`array_combine()`

`array_push()`

`array_merge_recursive()`

But none of these worked. Or I don't know how to get them to work.

HTML

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">E-posta</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="email" class="form-control email-address" name="email[]" placeholder="E-Posta giriniz">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input class="primary-radio" type="radio" name="primary[]" checked autocomplete="off"> <span
                    class="fas fa-star"></span>
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input class="ban-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="ban[]" autocomplete="off"> <span
                    class="fas fa-ban"></span>
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input class="invalid-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="invalid[]" autocomplete="off"> <span
                    class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

PHP

```php
public function add(Request $request)
{
    $emails = $request->input('email');
    $primary = $request->input('primary');
    $ban = $request->input('ban');
    $invalid = $request->input('invalid');

    $emailAddresses = array();

    foreach ($emails as $emailKey => $emailValue) {
        $emailAddresses[$emailKey] = [
            'emailAddress' => $emailValue,
            'invalid' => $invalid,
            'lower' => $emailAddresses,
            'ban' => $ban,
            'primary' => $primary
        ];
    }
    dd($emailAddresses);
}
```

Output

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:5 [▼
    "emailAddress" => "dodis@live.com"
    "invalid" => null
    "lower" => "dodis@live.com"
    "ban" => array:2 [▼
      0 => "on"
      1 => "on"
    ]
    "primary" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "on"
    ]
  ]
  1 => array:5 [▼
    "emailAddress" => "test@live.com"
    "invalid" => null
    "lower" => "test@live.com"
    "ban" => array:2 [▼
      0 => "on"
      1 => "on"
    ]
    "primary" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "on"
    ]
  ]
  2 => array:5 [▼
    "emailAddress" => "bundayok@live.com"
    "invalid" => null
    "lower" => "bundayok@live.com"
    "ban" => array:2 [▼
      0 => "on"
      1 => "on"
    ]
    "primary" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "on"
    ]
  ]
]
```

Such an output comes. It shouldn't be like that. Here's the example I want it to be.

```
0: {
        emailAddress: "bilgi@ekinciler.com.tr"
        invalid: false
        lower: "bilgi@ekinciler.com.tr"
        optOut: false
        primary: true
    }
1: {
        emailAddress: "muhasebe@ekinciler.com"
        invalid: false
        lower: "muhasebe@ekinciler.com"
        optOut: false
        primary: false
    }
```

I am sorry for my English. I hope I can. I would be glad if you help.

Comment: What do you mean about `merge`? You mean you need to transform your array?

Comment: The second array does not look that much different than the first one. As far as I see, the `ban` element vanished and the mail addresses look completely different. How should this be done automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below code,

What I have done is added array index to each loop to get correct value of that index, here your

```
"ban" => array:2 [▼
  0 => "on"
  1 => "on"
]
```

is array itself so you need 0 index for the first array data. and same applies for all the array.

```
public function add(Request $request)
{
    $emails = $request->input('email');
    $primary = $request->input('primary');
    $ban = $request->input('ban');
    $invalid = $request->input('invalid');

    $emailAddresses = array();

    $i = 0;

    foreach ($emails as $emailKey => $emailValue) {
        $emailAddresses[$emailKey] = [
            'emailAddress' => $emailValue,
            'invalid' => $invalid[$i]?$invalid[$i]:'',
            'lower' => $emailAddresses,
            'ban' => $ban[$i]?$ban[$i]:'',
            'primary' => $primary[$i]?$primary[$i]:''
        ];
        $i++;
    }

    dd($emailAddresses);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help but get this error "ErrorException Undefined offset: 1"

Comment: Okay, I figured it out. It is necessary to use the isset function. @Regolith